# mySql/Express GET request to a dynamic SELECT query in a React Native application

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, react-native, restful-architecture

I'm trying to make a GET request which will trigger a SELECT query from a mySQL database.  However, I need the request to be dynamic as the data that will be queried for depends upon user input.  The following is what I've come up with based on how I execute a POST request:

*The handlePress function gets triggered when its respective component is selected

```
handlePress = (inputId) => {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/testData', {
    "method": "GET",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      id: inputId
    })
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({newData: responseData}) 
  })
} 


app.get('/testData', function (req, res) {
  connection.query('select * from ticket_data where id = ' + req.body.id, function(error, results, fields) {
    if(error) {
      console.log('Error in GET / query')
    } else {
      res.send(results);
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured it out.  You have to use req.query; the way I was doing it was only valid for a POST request.  In case other's run into the same problem, here is my solution:

```
handlePress = (inputId) => {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/testData?id=' + inputID, {
    "method": "GET"
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({newData: responseData}) 
  })
} 


app.get('/testData', function (req, res) {
  connection.query('select * from ticket_data where id= ' + req.query.id, function(error, results, fields) {
    if(error) {
      console.log('Error in GET / query')
    } else {
      res.send(results);
    }
  })
})
```